# How to find sup and inf of this set?

Tags: real-analysis

I have this set $$X=\{\frac{\cos(\pi m)}{m}+\exp(-|n|),\, n\in \mathbb{Z}, m\in \mathbb{Z}^*\}$$

I know that $X$ is bounded, because for any m and n we have
$$
|\frac{\cos(\pi m)}{m}+\exp(-|n|)|\leq |\frac1m|+1\leq 2
$$

but how to find inf and sup of X?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know that $2$ is an upper bound for $X$.  Can you find a pair of values $(m,n)$ such that $$f(m,n) = \frac{\cos \pi m}{m} + e^{-|n|}$$ attains this upper bound?  If so, you have shown $\sup X = 2$, since the upper bound is tight.  If not, then what choice of $(m,n)$ gets you the largest possible value?

As for the infimum, can $f(m,n) < 0$?  What is $\inf e^{-|n|}$ in particular?  Then, for what choice of $m$ is $(\cos \pi m)/m$ as small as possible?

Comment: i don't this that we can get 2, for n=0 and m=2 we get 3/2, and for inf (X) for n goes to $\infty$ we have that $\exp(-|n|)$ goes to 0, and for m=1 we get -1 @heropup

Comment: @NoraNour Correct. One thing to note is that if $m, n$ may be chosen independently and $f(m,n) = g(m) + h(n)$ for suitable functions $g, h$, then $\sup f = \sup g + \sup h$ and $\inf f = \inf g + \inf h$.  If $m$ is not allowed to be negative, then the largest possible value of $(\cos \pi m)/m$ occurs for $m = 2$, since it is easy to see that $\cos \pi m = (-1)^m$ for all positive integers $m$.